# Elaboration of a vector space over $GF(2)$ with symmetric difference as addition operation.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

The example given below is from Golan's "Linear Algebra":

> [image]

But I have some questions regarding it.

My questions are:

1- What is the meaning of $GF(2)$ in this example, does it mean $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ and why is scalar multiplication defined specifically in this way?

2- How do we note that there is a bijective function from $V$ to $GF(2)^A$? And why does this bijective function assign a characteristic function? How do we know this?

3- How can I prove that $\chi_{A} + \chi_{B} = \chi_{A+B}$ and $\chi_{A} \chi_{B} = \chi_{A\cap B}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

Yes

**Question 2**

In general, for set $E$ with cardinal $\vert E \vert$, the cardinal of the power set $\mathcal P(E)$ is $2^{\vert E \vert}$. As $GF(2)$ has $2$ elements, the cardinal of $GF(2)^A$ is equal to the one of $V$ which is $2^{\vert A \vert}$. Equally of cardinals implies the existence of a bijection. You can verify that $X \mapsto \chi_X$ is indeed such a bijection.

One of the axioms of a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) $V$ is that $1 \cdot x =x$ for all $x \in V$. This is why $1 \cdot B$ is defined as $B$. Also in a vector space, one can prove that $0 \cdot x = x$ for all $x \in V$, therefore the definition here of $0 \cdot B = B$.

**Question 3**

Look at the different cases $x \in A \setminus B$, $x \in B \setminus A$ and $x \in A \cap B$ to prove the requested equalities. For example if $x \in A \setminus B$, you have $\chi_A(x) = 1$, $\chi_B(x) = 0$ and $\chi_{A+B}(x) = 1$.

Comment: The set $A$ in question doesn't need to be finite.

Comment: @Enmar You're right. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. $GF(2)$ is the field $\mathbb{Z/(2)}$. Scalar multiplication is defined in this way so that it satisfies the 4 scalar multiplication axioms for a vector space.
2. The function $V \rightarrow GF(2)^{A}$ is given to you as $B \mapsto \chi_{B}$. To see that it's bijective, verify that its inverse is the function $GF(2)^{A} \rightarrow V$ defined by $f \mapsto \{a\in A:f(a)=1\}$. Why a characteristic function was chosen is because it does the job.
3. Using $A$ here is possibly a typo; I think they should be using arbitrary elements $B,C \in V$. So to prove $\chi_{B}+\chi_{C}=\chi_{B+C}$ and $\chi_{B}\chi_{C}=\chi_{B\cap C}$ for any $B,C \in V$, you must show that $\chi_{B}(a)+\chi_{C}(a)=\chi_{B+C}(a)$ and $\chi_{B}(a)\chi_{C}(a)=\chi_{B\cap C}(a)$ for any $a \in A$. These require a tedious examination of cases: (i) $a \notin B \cup C$; (ii) $a \in B \setminus C$; (iii) $a \in C \setminus B$; (iv) $a \in B \cap C$.

Comment: So multiplying a number by a set means multiplying each element of this set by the number?

Comment: @hopefully, no. It means precisely what it says and has nothing to do with multiplication with numbers. In any vector space, if you multiply by $0$, you must get zero vector because of (quasi)distributivity condition, and if you multiply by $1$, you get the same vector. In other words, multiplying by $0$ is constant function mapping everything to zero vector, and multiplying by $1$ is identity function on any vector space.